# How does Stroustrup's Can_Copy template work?

Tags: c++, templates

Stroustrup provides a [Can_copy template](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#constraints). How does it work?

```
template<class T1, class T2> struct Can_copy {
    static void constraints(T1 a, T2 b) { T2 c = a; b = a; }
    Can_copy() { void(*p)(T1,T2) = constraints; }
};
```

In particular, why does he need the line `void(*p)(T1,T2) = constraints;` instead of an empty constructor? Are compilers allowed to produce only the functions a particular template instance uses as an optimisation?

Comment: It is not just **allowed** but **required** that compilers only "produce" the functions actually used. That way it is ok if some functions cannot be compiled for types that don't need them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because not used member functions in templates don't exist in generated code, so to check constrainst you would have to call `constraints()` explicitly somewhere.

This way code for `constraints()` is generated, so constraints are checked in compile time (and that is the purpose of `Can_copy`).

Answer (score 4):

C++03 §14.7.1p1:

> Unless a class template specialization has been explicitly instantiated (14.7.2) or explicitly specialized (14.7.3), the class template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a completely-defined object type or when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics of the program. The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit instantiation of the declarations, **but not of the definitions** or default arguments, of the class member functions, member classes, static data members and member templates; …

Thus, this code *cannot* instantiate Can_copy::constraints:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
struct Can_copy {
  static void constraints(T1 a, T2 b) { T2 c = a; b = a; }
  Can_copy() { /* note the change here */ }
};

template<class Container>
void draw_all(Container& c) {
  typedef typename Container::value_type T;
  Can_copy<T,Shape*>(); // accept containers of only Shape*s
}
```

But, in the original code, when Can_copy's ctor is instantiated, as it must be when it is used, its body (definition) is as well, and that triggers instantiation of Can_copy::constraints.

You can see this same problem in reverse, where an explicit instantiation gives you everything, even something you don't want:

```
typedef std::list<int>::iterator Iter;
std::reverse_iterator<Iter> x;  // Implicit instantiation; works.

template std::reverse_iterator<Iter>;
// Explicit instantiation; fails to instantiate op+ and other operators used
// for random access iterators from reverse_iterator.
```

Answer (score 3):

Meant to be informative, not an answer (not deserving of an upvote):

In C++0x you will have improved facilities for this in the header `<type_traits>`.

```
std::is_copy_constructible<T1>::value;
std::is_copy_assignable<T1>::value;
std::is_constructible<T1, T2>::value;
std::is_assignable<T1, T2>::value;
std::is_convertible<T1, T2>::value;
```

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3225.pdf

search for "[meta]".

Comment: Thanks, still learning the ropes around here.  Got a pointer on how to make it a community wiki?  Did a brief search, but didn't find it.

Comment: there is a check-box at the bottom-right of the edit-box saying "community wiki". A community-wiki answer will cause no rep change for upvotes or downvotes and allows other users with only 100rep to edit it. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Answer (score 2):

The usage of the template is as simple as `Can_copy<int, char>();`

If an instance of T1 cannot be copied to an instance of T2, the code `b = a` wouldn't *compile* at all. The same way, if an instance of T2 cannot be initialized with the instance of T1, the code `T2 c = a;` wouldn't compile.

So, if `T1` cannot be copied to `T2`, the line containing the template usage won't compile.

The whole construct produces (almost) no code, and is easily removed by the optimizer.