# C++ checking types at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, types, constraints

I was reading Bjarne Stroustrup's FAQ on C++ and reading about constraints on type parameters and ways to enforce certain constraints at compile time without getting ridiculous template errors and came accross this example:

```
 template<class T1, class T2> 
    struct Can_copy {
        static void constraints(T1 a, T2 b) { T2 c = a; b = a; }
        Can_copy() { 
            void(*p)(T1, T2) = constraints;
        }
    };
```

However, I'm not quite sure how is this evalutated at compile time? Whats the use of assigning constraints to the function pointer? Is this some kind of implicit invocation of constraints?

Sorry if this is an obvious question, literally only been reading C++ for two days however have experience in other languages.

Comment: Maybe not dupe, but relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072554/how-does-stroustrups-can-copy-template-work

Comment: I fail to see why `c` is needed.  It has the same type as `b`.  Or is it to test both copy constructor and `operator = ()` ?  If that's the case, he could have made it more obvious by declaring `T2 c(a);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think like a compiler. "Assigning constraints to the function pointer" forces the code generation, which forces the type resolution, which forces the generation of assignment operators to the given types.

Now, imagine that either `c=a` or `b=a` cannot be resolved due to the necessary assignment operator not being available for the given pair of types. In such a case the compilation will fail.